# How do I create a search page?

Tags: search

I have the *Search API* and the *Solr search* modules installed. In /admin/config/search/search-api, I see my server and index created and with status set to *OK*. I can see on the index view page that my content is indexed correctly.

> [image: Server and index ok]

I did not use the *Solr Search Defaults* module because I have removed the default Article content type, and I don't want to recreate it. Without this content type, there is an error when activating the module.

How can I create a search page displaying all indexed results (for anonymous users, not in BO)?

One tutorial shows that *Solr Search Defaults* module uses views. I've created a view, where in *View settings > Show* I've selected *Ideas* index.
In the view, *Format > Show* is set to *Rendered entity*. *Search index* is the view mode. I have a page, but no content is displayed.
No filters are required, and all are exposed.
[image]

Other tutorial says I should create a search page in *Configurations > Search and metadata > Search pages* menu, but I don't have that menu.

---

Here are my *Fields* for Ideas index.
[image]
Here is another view I've tried, with *Show > fields*
[image]
Here are my error logs, there is a Notice:
[image]
Here is what I see using `{{ kint(page.content) }}` on my Search results page:
[image]
If I create a view with *VIEW SETTINGS > Show > Content* my content IS diplayed correctly.

Comment: You probably have one or more filters set to "required" - if you clear those flags all results should be displayed I think

Comment: No, no filters are required. I've added my view to the description of the question, you can see.

Comment: You don’t need the defaults module. Once content is being indexed you can either create a Views page or you can code it yourself using the Solarium client.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the searc api module:

1) goto: /admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/edit

If you want for example to search for both Users & Content at once, make sure that both entities for Content & Users under the Data sources section are checked.

2) Goto: http://site8.dd:8083/admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/fields

This page is used to choose which are the fields you want to be indexed for your search.

So make sure on this page that all the fields you want to search your entities by are added to your entities; If not,
add any field using the **+Add Fields** button.

3) On the same page: http://site8.dd:8083/admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/fields

Any field you add, it has its own data type which you have also the permission to change it.

As per the data type table available at the bottom of the page:

> Fulltext fields are analyzed fields which are made available for
>   fulltext search.  This data type should be used for any fields
>   (usually with free text input by users)  which you want to search for
>   individual words.

so in your view, if you want to use the **Fulltext search** to search for your contents, every indexed field on this page should also be set to **Fulltext** data type.

4) Goto: http://site8.dd:8083/admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index

And make sure that the index Status bar is 100% and so all your contents are indexed to be searchable.

When you have done the above, create a new view as per below:

- Show: **index default content index**
- Check **Create page** box
- Display format **Grid**
- Hit **save and edit** button.

**Within the views configuration page:**

*Under add fields section:*

- add any fields you want and make sure the field title has the **(indexed field)** text.

*Under the filter criteria section:*

- add the **fulltext search** field and exposed to visitors.

Here you go, visit your search page and enjoy.

If none of the above helped you, feel free to ask any other question in comments or update your current question.

Comment: Thank you. I had all this, and now tried also your way to use _Format > Show > Fields_. It still displays nothing.
I expect to display all indexed content if there are no filters used. Right?

Comment: Yes if no filters are used, all the indexed content should be displayed for you. Did you try 1) clear your caches ? 2) Re-index all your content ? 3) add all necessary field for your content from the search api configuration page ? If you did all the above and still no luck, i am affraid you will have to give access your view and configuration page so i can debug it for you !

Comment: I've done 1-2-3. I've just updated the description with more screenshots, please, see if it helps.
The site is on local environment only now, so no access is possible.

Comment: I have checked all your configuration and everything seems to be correct ! In this page **Here are my Fields for Ideas index**, try to change the boost value for the **fulltext** type fields to a higher value for example 13.0 and if possible and you have time re-create your view using simplytest.me platform for easier debugging

Comment: I've set values to 13.0, then cleared caches, recreated a view just to test: no changes.
I really do not figure out how to use https://simplytest.me/, it seems Solr Search module does not exist there.

Comment: No worries, i will setup one simplytest.me testing site for you and i will try to recreate your issue... i will revert back to you as soon as i finish

Comment: Thank you. If you are interested to see the code, it is here https://github.com/oksana-skotar/interiors

Comment: I have an idea that a problem may be linked to a template. I use a theme, and maybe there the template is not correct for a search page. I see that simple "page.html.twig" template is used for this page. But how can I check if `{{ page.content }}` has all what is needed to display my search results?
I've updated the description with Kint results.

Comment: This seems way off track. All that is needed is a Views page to show the results - nothing else. If you suspect a theme issue, switch to Bartik to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I have created a test website here (https://df8mk.ply.st/search-for-articles) similar to your configuration and all is working properly for me. You may check the configuration on the test website by using **username/password:** oksana/oksana about the theme issue, as Kevin suggested revert back to the default bartik theme and check your results again.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! But I can not access the link (https://df8mk.ply.st/search-for-articles has error 404 and https://www.df8mk.ply.st/search-for-articles says that the site is dangerous and there is no option to go there.

Comment: @Kevin You're right, I've switched to Bartik, it does not display content as well.

Comment: The test website i have made for you used simolutest.me platform and that means that the website will expire after 12 hours and you will no longer have access to it

Comment: Ok, that's frustrating. Sorry, it was night in my zone. I'm trying to deploy on a hosting now.